# vlcj - audio callback

Tags: java, vlcj, pitch-shifting

I need audio data callback while vlcj is playing the video file. 
And then I want to add some effect (pitch shifting, etc..) on that audio and direct sound out. 
I found vedio buffer call back in vlcj documentation, but not audio callback.

if i can get the audio callback, i can use other library such as soundtouch, etc...
or please let me know other alternative like as vlcj.

i just success with nVLC + NAudio on Windows.

It is possible with vlcj? Should I use gstreamer (gstreamer-java) or MPlayer?

regards,
-pph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vlcj 2.4.0 adds a new DirectAudioPlayer and associated DirectAudioPlayerComponent.

and sound touch wrapper 
http://www.aplu.ch/home/apluhomex.jsp?site=44

make me complete.

Comment: Hi I would like to do something similar,but for visualization, so during playing a video/audio I would like to use the audio callBacks to draw a visualizer...  do you have some code example with I can start from? Any suggestions will be appreciated...